# Get attributes of a Web Element

Tags: c#, php, html

Is there any technique that can be used to get attributes of an element in a web page? I'm trying to get properties of elements such as Links, Buttons, check boxes and Radio Buttons for test automation purposes to make it more easier. But I couldn't find any solution. I heard that CODEDUI can be used. If so, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned `html` tag in your question, one solution is using jQuery like this:

```
$( elemement ).attr( "attribute" )
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: You should add this code to your script block (inside a `script` tag) or through a .js file, and call it where ever you need. If you don't know about jQuery or javascript it's better to first take a look at those topics and then you can use my code.

Comment: Is there a method that uses C#?

Comment: @AshanPerera for server controls (the controls with attribute runat="server") you can do it with c#.

Comment: Can you please explain it further?

Answer (score 0):

you do not get property of html page with program language php and c# you should useing jquery and Similar libraries or JavaScript .

for this problem you must using this code in select html with jquery :

```
<select id="selectVehicle">
 <option value="1" data-year="2011">Mazda</option>
 <option value="2" data-year="2015">Honda</option>
 <option value="3" data-year="2008">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="4" data-year="2005">Toyota</option>
</select>

$("#selectVehicle").change(function () {
  alert($(this).find(':selected').data("year"));
});
```

or get attribute of elements :

```
$(this).attr('data-fullText');
```